# Google penalty a page that served after sending 404 response?

Tags: seo, http-status-code-404

If i send a 404 response code and after that i serve my home page like

```
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
include("index.php");
```

Will that cause to penalty or ban the page or its content?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to google: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2409439?hl=en
A page that have a status of 404 will neither affect your rank nor will cause a penalty for your website.

Comment: Then this should clarify things to you:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/181708?hl=en&ref_topic=1724951